# Console error in any rake command in my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, error-console

I'm having some problem when running any rake command in my rails application:

```
humberto@asterix:/var/www/avante-q-a$ rake db

/home/humberto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/pry-0.9.9.6/lib/pry.rb:11: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_HOOKS
/home/humberto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/pry-0.9.9.6/lib/pry.rb:23: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_PRINT
/home/humberto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/pry-0.9.9.6/lib/pry.rb:48: warning: already initialized constant SIMPLE_PRINT
/home/humberto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/pry-0.9.9.6/lib/pry.rb:57: warning: already initialized constant CLIPPED_PRINT
/home/humberto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/pry-0.9.9.6/lib/pry.rb:62: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_EXCEPTION_HANDLER
/home/humberto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/pry-0.9.9.6/lib/pry.rb:68: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_EXCEPTION_WHITELIST
/home/humberto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/pry-0.9.9.6/lib/pry.rb:71: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_PROMPT
/home/humberto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/pry-0.9.9.6/lib/pry.rb:82: warning: already initialized constant SIMPLE_PROMPT
/home/humberto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/pry-0.9.9.6/lib/pry.rb:84: warning: already initialized constant SHELL_PROMPT
/home/humberto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/pry-0.9.9.6/lib/pry.rb:91: warning: already initialized constant NAV_PROMPT
/home/humberto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/pry-0.9.9.6/lib/pry.rb:107: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_CONTROL_D_HANDLER
/home/humberto/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/pry-0.9.9.6/lib/pry.rb:121: warning: already initialized constant DEFAULT_SYSTEM
rake aborted!
cannot load such file -- pry/nav

(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I've already run bundle install and it worked succesfull. Do someone know what is missing here? Thanks since now.

Comment: why are you using such an ancient version of pry? :)

Answer (score 1):

You should try re-running it within a bundler context:

```
bundle exec rake db
```

Bundle exec loads bundler first and hooks all of the gems into the current environment before rake is loaded.

Comment: unfortunately runing with bundle exec gives me the same error